# need help solving 'Passing argument 2 of ‘strstr’ makes pointer from integer without a cast, strstr(fline, '\n')'

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<unistd.h>
int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
        FILE *fp1;
        FILE *fp2;
        char fline[100];
        char *newline;
        int count = 0, occ1 = 0, occ2 = 0;
if(argc==1){
        printf("You only entered the program name");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

if(argc==2){
        printf("You only entered the first file name");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

if(argc==3){
        printf("You only entered the first file name and key word");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

if(argc==4){
        printf("You only entered the first filename/keyword and second file name");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

if(argc==5){
        fp1 = fopen(argv[1], "r");
        fp2 = fopen(argv[3], "r");

        if(fp1 == NULL){
                printf("File could not be opened");
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }//end fp1
        if(fp2 == NULL){
                printf("File could not be opened");
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }//end fp2
        while(fgets(fline, 100, fp1)!=NULL){
                count++;
                if((newline=strstr(fline, '\n'))!=NULL)
                        *newline='\0';
                if(strstr(fline,argv[2])!=NULL)
                        occ1++;
        }

        while(fgets(fline, 100, fp2)!=NULL){
                count++;
                if((newline=strstr(fline, '\n'))!=NULL)
                        *newline='\0';
                if(strstr(fline,argv[4])!=NULL)
                        occ2++;
        }//end while fp2
        printf("football Count: %d", occ1);
        printf("username Count: %d", occ2);
        fclose(fp1);
        fclose(fp2);
        exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}//end arg5

singleThread.c: In function ‘main’:
singleThread.c:50:29: error: invalid type argument of unary ‘*’ (have ‘int’)
   50 |   if((newline=strstr(fline, *'\n'))!=NULL)
      |                             ^~~~~
singleThread.c:58:43: error: invalid type argument of unary ‘*’ (have ‘int’)
   if((newline=strstr(fline, *'\n'))!=NULL)
```

This is the Error I am receiving. I was hoping someone would be able to help me out. THe point of \n in the strstr is to tell the code to continue onto the next line within the file. However, I understand it is asking for a double pointer. I'm just not sure how to complete this while still having it move onto the next line.
Any help would be amazing, thank you :)

Comment: `'\n'` is a single character. `"\n"` is a null-terminated string.

Comment: The name of the function gives you a clue. `strstr` expects two string parameters. Given that, perhaps you wanted to use `strchr` instead?

Comment: My code is trying to find strings of characters within a textile. so if a text file includes a word _football_, foot*ball, and football. It would count 2 of the three. That kinda made strchr not work for me

Comment: I don't follow that comment, @TickleToes123.  Nor how what you are trying to do has anything to do with continuing to next line.  Are you perhaps saying that you want to recognize target words that are split across lines of the file?  How does changing newlines to null characters actually help you?

Comment: As a separate matter, your program appears to have some potential problems, including at least (i) undercounting if the target word appears more than once on a line; (ii) overcounting if a target word appears as a substring of a different word that appears in the file; and (iii) possibly undercounting if the input file contains lines longer than your buffer.

Comment: Commenters are referring to the `strstr` in the newline removal `strstr(fline, '\n')` not to the search matching in `strstr(fline,argv[2])`. Arguably, you don't actually need to remove those trailing newlines kept by `fgets()` because the program arguments won't have them.

Comment: @JohnBollinger Thank you for the feedback. I'll try to find a solution to it.

Comment: @TickleToes123, if you need to read your files on a line-by-line basis then `fgets()` is the way to go, but do you actually need that?  If end-of-line is is significant only as whitespace for you, then you might be better served by using `fscanf()` to read the files in whitespace-delimited pieces.  That function gets a lot of mostly-deserved criticism, but it might nevertheless be a better tool for your particular job.